# C# Parallel Execution Thread Limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a simple test which just logs the time when a concurrent request starts and then sleeps for a second.

```
static void TestParallelism()
{
    int expectedThreadCount = 100;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId, expectedThreadCount);
    var module = new WCFCompositeModule();
    module.Initialize(new Keywords());

    var range = Enumerable.Range(0, expectedThreadCount);
    var startTimes = new ConcurrentBag<DateTime>();

    var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = expectedThreadCount };
    Parallel.ForEach(range, i =>
    {
        startTimes.Add(DateTime.Now);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });

    foreach (var time in startTimes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0: HH:mm:ss.fff}", time));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I execute this with 100 expected threads I can see 12 different distinct start times all varying by 1 seconds. Instead of seeing them all start at the same second.

Sample

> 13:59:27.475 
>   13:59:26.473
>   13:59:25.473
>   13:59:24.471
>   13:59:23.470
>   13:59:22.469

Is this occurring because sleep blocks the thread?

Comment: What happened when you tried it without the sleep?

Comment: Without the sleep everything works as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be expecting this code to launch 100 threads, however

```
MaxDegreeOfParallelism = expectedThreadCount
```

Only sets a maximum, not a minimum, the system will dispatch it to however many (and at most MaxDegreeOfParallelism) threads.

Unless you have a 100 core machine it's not likely to use up 100 threads, so it's using X threads and then they all block for 1 second before it dispatch the next batch on the same previous X threads. Here x is 100/12 = 8.333333, so if you're seeing 12 different times it's starting at least 12 different batchs meaning it executes somewhere between 8 to 9 threads at a time, if you have a 4 core system with hyperthreading or a 8 core system this is probably the default behavior.

Comment: So if I set the minimum threads it should work or because the sleep still blocks I should see similar results?

Comment: @johnny5 the sleep blocks the calling thread, so if you have 100 thread each of them will wait 1 second but it doesn't mean they can't all start at the same time regardless. However there's no easy way to set the minimum, when you're using the TPL you're letting it decide what's best, if you want explicit control, create and manage the threads manually (but unless you have a very specific workload, you're more likely to perform worse than better).